# Как подключить ZeroMQ (zmq) на Open Server php 7.2 Ratchet Windows 10

Tags: php, ratchet, zeromq

Я 1 день просто мучаюсь. Все сделал правильно, все что видел в интернете.
В документации `Ratchet` - [тут](http://socketo.me/docs/push) сказано установить ZeroMQ.
На сайте я честно не разобрался как установить. Поэтому пошел в интернет и искать.
Все говорят что нужно скачать файл zmq [тут](https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows). У меня система 64, скачивать `NTS` или `TS` я не знаю. Но пробовал оба: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После установки я извлек файлы `libzmq.dll, php_zmq.dll` (для уверенности что попал куда - то) в пути: `C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.2`, `C:\OpenServer\modules\php\PHP_7.2\ext`.
Дальше нашел ini файл по пути: `C:\OpenServer\userdata\config\PHP_7.2_php.ini` и добавил следующие:

```
[ZMQ]
extension=php_zmq.dll
```

После перезагрузил Open Server:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Потом зашел в консоль Open Server и набрал `php -m`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Ни чего нет.

И я видел что нужно в консоли написать `deplister php_zmq.dll`. Написал, и вот что выводит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С этой информацией я не знаю что делать.

В документации `Ratchet` - сказано как установить и сам Ratchet и zmq с помощи composer
Что я сделал:

1. скопировал файл: composer.json и положил в директорию проекта `{ "autoload": { "psr-4": { "MyApp\\": "src" } }, "require": { "cboden/ratchet": "0.4.*", "react/zmq": "0.2.*|0.3.*" } }`
2. Установил composer.phar.
3. Запустил с помощи консоли `php composer.phar install`

Пишет вот что:

> Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.
> Problem 1
> - react/zmq[v0.2.0, ..., v0.3.0] require ext-zmq * -> it is missing from your system. Install or enable PHP's zmq extension.
> - Root composer.json requires react/zmq 0.2.*|0.3.* -> satisfiable by react/zmq[v0.2.0, v0.3.0].
> To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in your .ini files:
> - C:\openserver\modules\php\PHP_7.1\php.ini
> You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
> You are using a snapshot build of Composer 2, which may be the cause of the problem. Run `composer self-update --stable` and then try again. In case it solves the problem, please report an issue mentioning Composer 2.

**PHP версия вот такая -> PHP 7.1.33**

Что делать? Я серьезно не знаю что делать. Помогите пожалуйста. И вообще если делать это все на другом удаленном сервере у хостеров, там так-же все нужно делать? Или может тогда вообще не нужно?

Comment: Можете подсказать хоть тогда, как это делать на OpenServer, может я что то не так именно на OpenServer делаю

Answer (score 1):

Я решил это.
Это очень странно, я думаю у вас так-же будет работать.

Как делал я для PHP 7.1:

1. Зашел [на сайт](https://pecl.php.net/package/zmq/1.1.3/windows) и скачал `7.1 Thread Safe (TS) x64` - у меня 64 bit. (На PHP 7.2 устанавливайте `7.2 Thread Safe (TS) x64`)
2. Когда скачал архив, я файл `libzmq.dll` положил в `C:\openserver\modules\php\PHP_7.1` и `C:\openserver\modules\http\Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1+Nginx_1.21\bin`. Как я понял вы должны положить этот файл еще и в Apache, у меня она по такому пути. Находите bin, и кидаете туда папку. В настройках Open Server у меня так:
   [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

- `Apache_2.4-PHP_7.0-7.1+Nginx_1.21`

3. файл `libsodium.dll` кидаю в `C:\openserver\modules\php\PHP_7.1`.
4. файл `php_zmq.dll` кидаю в `C:\openserver\modules\php\PHP_7.1\ext`.
5. Иду в ini (говорят по этому пути ни чего не сработает а у меня работает! Конечно где выше мой вопрос я пробовал все пути.) : `C:\openserver\modules\php\PHP_7.1\php.ini`.
6. пишите туда в самом низу: `[ZMQ] extension = php_zmq.dll`. [ZMQ] - должна быть на другой строчки.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

7. Перезагружайте open server :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

8. заходите в консоль:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

9. Самый страшный пункт, был для меня, надеюсь для вас он так-же останется в прошлом.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

10.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]